# can't read csv file using pd.read_csv() method in test class

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pytest, sys.path

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

sys.path.insert(0, sys.argv[2])
sys.path.insert(1, sys.argv[3])

from training import CustomerSegmentation

class TestCustomerSegmentation:

    dataset = pd.read_csv(
    sys.path.pop(1),
    parse_dates=["InvoiceDate"],
    )
```

then by giving command line arguments:

`python3 -m pytest test_training.py "customer-segmentation-v1" "customer-segmentation-v1/customer_data.csv"`

it gives an error:

ERROR: not found: /customer-segmentation-v1/customer_data.csv
(no name '/customer-segmentation-v1/customer_data.csv' in any of [])

I want my test class to read the csv data file that is present on the path given as command line argument.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a virtual environment for your project first and running the codes in the Virtual environment.

```
py -m venv environment
environment\Scripts\activate
```

Try creating an environment and run your project inside the environment.

Comment: can we resolve this error apart from creating virtual environment?

Answer (score 0):

you must add the file into the same folder. or maybe this link is useful for you here https://www.machinelearningplus.com/pandas/pandas-read_csv-completed/